# Is there a way to bulk download Landsat data through cmd prompt or Python?

Tags: python, raster, landsat, landsat-8

I know I can download landsat data through earth explorer and they have their own Bulk Downloader here: https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/EEHelp/BulkDownloadApplication

But I am wondering if there is somehting similar to the way Sentinel lets you bulkdownload, through their API in Python? Where you can give it an area of interest and a date range and it downloads anything that meets that criteria.